# MySQL: "= true" vs "is true" on BOOLEAN. When is it advisable to use which one? And Which one is vendor independent?

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL provides 2 ways to check truth value of `boolean` columns, those are `column_variable = true` and `column_variable is true`. I created a table, inserted few values & tried a few `select` statements. Here are the results:

First I created this table:

```
mysql> create table bool_test (
    -> id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    -> flag boolean );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)
```

Then I inserted 4 rows:

```
mysql> insert into bool_test(flag) values (true),(false),(9),(null);

mysql> select * from bool_test;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    0 |
|  3 |    9 |
|  4 | NULL |
```

Here are all the `select` queries I fired on this table:

```
mysql> select * from bool_test where flag;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  3 |    9 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.49 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where flag = true;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where flag is true;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  3 |    9 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where flag = false;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  2 |    0 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where flag is false;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  2 |    0 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where !flag;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  2 |    0 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where not flag;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  2 |    0 |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where flag != true;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  2 |    0 |
|  3 |    9 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where flag is not true;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  2 |    0 |
|  4 | NULL |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where flag != false;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  3 |    9 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from bool_test where flag is not false;
+----+------+
| id | flag |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  3 |    9 |
|  4 | NULL |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My Question is: when is it advisable to use `is`/`is not` and when is it advisable to use `=`/`!=`  with `true`/`false` ? Which one is vendor independent?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

MySQL is actually fooling you. It [doesn't have a boolean column type at all](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html):

> `BOOL`, `BOOLEAN`
>
> These types are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`. A value of zero is considered
> false. Nonzero values are considered true:

Also, the [boolean literals are not such](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/boolean-literals.html):

> The constants `TRUE` and `FALSE` evaluate to 1 and 0, respectively.

Considering that:

- Many database systems do not have booleans either (not at least in standard SQL and column types)
- MySQL doesn't have an easy way to enforce `0` or `1` in `BOOLEAN`

My conclusion would be:

- You'll have to use `WHERE IS flag` or just `WHERE flag` because `=` simply doesn't work correctly. Which one, is possibly a matter of preference.
- Whatever you choose, no option will be vendor independent. For instance, Oracle won't even run either of them.

---

**Edit:** if cross-platform is a must, I'd go for this:

```
WHERE flag=0
WHERE flag<>0
```

I'm sure we've all done it lots of times.

Comment: I run tests, `WHERE 1=1` works fine, `WHERE 1` isn't. Insane. My world become sad today.

Comment: @Jones That syntax doesn't seem to be SQL. Feel free to ask a question and don't forget to tag the language accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean with "because = simply doesn't work correctly"?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei Look at the question: `flag is true` matches `9` but `flag = true` doesn't.

Answer (score 22):

If the `flag` column is indexed and all values are either 0 or 1, `where flag = true` is much faster than `where flag is true`.

During our testing, `is true` resulted in a “full table scan” and took 1.121 seconds, while `= true` was executed with “key lookup” and only took 0.167 seconds. The table had about 3 million rows.

Comment: What about just passing the flag after all is a boolean value... is it faster? slower? as in `SELECT * FROM example WHERE flag`

Comment: @Erubiel It's identical to `WHERE flag IS TRUE`. It did a full table scan.