# How to restrict a specific row being deleted in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using `jComboBox` to select a Supplier from table so I have created -1 `id` row in a table for "none" selected Supplier.

-1 row is also appearing to user where I've fetched all records in 
   `jTable`.

I don't want user delete this row may either accidentally or consciously.

So may I have something like this?
I'm using MySQL and Java.

```
String comName = (String) jSupplrsComboBox.getSelectedItem();

            Suppliers suppliers = manager.searchSuppCompny(comName);
            if (comName.equals("none")) {
                receivings.getSuppliers().setId(-1);
                receivings.setSuppliers(suppliers);
            }
            receivings.setSuppliers(suppliers);
```

Fetched    `Suppliers` to     `jComboBox` and just manually addd "none" text  so it doesn't match in     `Suppliers` table.

Comment: I don't think a "no supplier" thing should even be in the database.

Comment: To expand on @f1sh 's reply -- having a dummy record in the db is just asking for trouble -- you will have to remember to exclude it whenever you write a query involving that table, which will make your code more complicated, error prone, and potentially slower. Just add the special value to the combo box when it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried myself and where I'm retrieving records I changed code:

```
DefaultTableModel suppliersModel = (DefaultTableModel) jSuppliersTable.getModel();
for(Suppliers suppliers : manager.allSuppliers()) {
    suppliersModel.addRow(new Object[]{suppliers.getId()});

    int id = (Integer) suppliersModel.getValueAt(0, 0);
    if(id == -1) {
        suppliersModel.removeRow(0);
    }
```

That retrieve records after first row which is -1     `id` in the database table.
Tahnks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but if you're utilizing a `JComboBox`, I imagine you're filtering your database by the supplier indicated by the comboBox selection. This also means your comboBox model needs to be populated with entries that exist in your database.

This is a quick way to set Strings to the ComboBox from an Enum, passing entries from the database should work in a similar way, but ensuring duplication does not exist may need to be addressed

```
jSupplrsComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(SupplierId.values()));
```

From link [Java - Check Boxes in a JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573159/java-check-boxes-in-a-jcombobox), response by Jonathan Feinberg might be better suited for more than one filter.

As for MYSQL, I'm assuming you have access to make modifications, it may be better if you add an extra field, say isValid, to indicate if said entry is valid or not. In which case you can filter on `jSupplrsComboBox.getSelectedItem()` with an additional `WHERE isValid = 1`. 
But your question was geared more towards Java than MYSQL, so I won't mention more on that. Check out [MySQL Boolean Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800881/mysql-true-vs-is-true-on-boolean-when-is-it-advisable-to-use-which-one) and associated links for more on that.

Comment: Then perhaps the second half of my answer, where I mentioned adding an isValid column to your database table.
Otherwise, I don't fully understand what it is you're asking