# MySQL UDF and diagnostic selects - function does not work even if selects are not run

Tags: mysql

The database is MySQL 5.7 (and unfortunately it is not possible to upgrade to 8.0).

Please consider the following

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spTest $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnTest $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spTest(_debug BIT, OUT _output CHAR(10))
BEGIN   
    SET _output = '123';
    IF _debug THEN
        SELECT _output;
    END IF;
END $$

CREATE FUNCTION fnTest() RETURNS CHAR(10)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _result CHAR(10);
    CALL spTest(0,_result);
    RETURN _result;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Just for the context : the real purpose of wrapping the procedure into function is to workaround MySQL 5.7 inability to call UDF recursively.

On top of that I wanted to implement debugging. I am aware that there are no direct SELECTs possible while UDF is executed. So I wanted to turn them off by additional param.

I was suprised to see that running `SELECT fnTest()` does not return any result.
Things come back to what I have expected when totally commenting out diagnostic SELECT from the procedure body:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest(_debug BIT, OUT _output CHAR(10))
BEGIN   
    SET _output = '123';
    /*
    IF _debug THEN
        SELECT _output;
    END IF;
    */
END $$
```

Now `SELECT fnTest()` returns '123' as one might suppose.

Apparently the engine does not check if an output is really made but rather if any SELECTs to output are coded (in one of my tests I have replaced `IF _debug THEN` with `IF 0=1 THEN` and it did not change the test result.

Is there any possible way to create procedure to wrap within the UDF that could still generate debug output?

Comment: Function cannot return a rowset, both explicitly and from nested stored object.

Comment: *Is there any possible way to create procedure to wrap within the UDF that could still generate debug output?* No problems. Create debug table and insert needed debug data into it. But remember - if a query fails then all data written to this debug table will be rollbacked (i.e. it will be removed).

Comment: @Akina _Function cannot return a rowset, both explicitly and from nested stored object_. Sure, I was aware of that. What surprised me is that rowset "hidden" by `IF 0=1` clause also prevents the function from executing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: "= true" vs "is true" on BOOLEAN. When is it advisable to use which one? And Which one is vendor independent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800881/mysql-true-vs-is-true-on-boolean-when-is-it-advisable-to-use-which-one) https://dbfiddle.uk/VH7AmfuZ

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks. Not really :). I am not trying to build proper condition but rather I am surprised that if SELECT to is not executed under no circumstances (but exist in the code) - it still blocks UDF.